# Is commenting junit test in Android Studio a safe way?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I recently migrated from `Eclipse` to `Android Studio` and I'm using `Android Studio 1.5.1`. Before when I started Android Studio, I got this error:

```
Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
```

After searching in Google and trying some proposed options, only `commenting junit test` in `app/build.gradle` solved the problem:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

But I want to know is this a good and **safe** option to resolve that problem? For example does it cause any problem in future?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the following to your `build.gradle` file and it should work fine.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

Comment: I had tried this way before but did not work for me.

Comment: better use `mavenCentral()` isntead of the url. as in `repositories { mavenCentral() }`